# Frame dropping when using AVAssetWriter?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, frame, avassetwriter

I’m working on an app that processes video frames, draws effects on the frame and saves them. When saving the video using AVAssetWriter I get stutters in the resulting video, but when I reduce the amount of processing on every frame, then stutter is reduced.

Writing and processing are on separate processes.

Every processed frame is dispatched in a queue for writing.

Here is the code:

```
_writingQueue.async {
    autoreleasepool {
        synchronized(self) {
            if self._status.rawValue >= VideoRecordingModelStatus.finishingRecordingPart1.rawValue {
                return
            }

            if !self._haveStartedSession {
                self._assetWriter?.startSession(atSourceTime: CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(sampleBuffer))
                self._haveStartedSession = true
            }

            let input = (mediaType == AVMediaType.video) ? self._videoInput : self._audioInput

            while !(input?.isReadyForMoreMediaData ?? false) {}

            let success = input!.append(sampleBuffer)
            if !success {
                let error = self._assetWriter?.error
                synchronized(self) {
                    self.transitionToStatus(.failed, error: error as NSError?)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Resulting video](https://youtu.be/z3UJxKVUIOM)